Mathematical expression of the constraint on the sides of a triangle
I was looking at Wikipedia on the constraints for a triangle inequality  here.
Given $a+b>c, b+c>a,c+a>b$,
they arrive at the conclusion that $\max(a,b,c)<a+b+c-\max(a,b,c)$.
How do you prove this ?

What does that inequality mean if,  say, $\max(a,b,c)=a$?

The largest of $a,b,c$ is smaller than the sum of the other two.

Assume w.l.o.g.  that $a=\max(a,b,c)$ is the largest of the three sides.
Then $a+b+c-\max(a,b,c)=b+c$, and your inequality
$$
(*)\qquad \max(a,b,c)<a+b+c-\max(a,b,c)
$$
becomes equivalent to
$$
a<b+c
$$
which is the triangle inequality. Note that, on the other hand, (*) is actually equivalent to all three triangle inequalities,  as since we assumed that $a$ is the largest, then $b<a+c$ and $c<a+b$ follow automatically.

thanks a lot for your insight !
